# DbContext Multiple Inheritance

Tags: entity-framework

The design of EF forces developers to inherit the DbContext class. Some reusable libraries (such as ASP.NET Identity) typically provides its functionality using the same inheritance route, i.e. by providing the IdentityDbContext base-class.

But obviously this won't work if you have 2 such libraries, e.g. requiring you to inherit from IdentityDbContext and CmsDbContext at the same time, which is obviously impossible to do on .NET. The result that I want is to have an application-dbcontext that contains both the models from my identity module and my cms module (I won't be able to separate this to 2 dbcontexts since that would mean I will end up with multiple connections and transactions, and that my models can only reference to either identity or cms entities, but not both).

It's hard to believe that this question hasn't seemed to be asked around EF community, but this seems like a horrendously bad ORM design. Inheritance only lets you to have strictly linear modularisation. (As a comparison, in NHibernate, ISession and your Configuration are 2 separate things, therefore you can use discovery process to build up your mapping-configuration from different unrelated modules, without messing with my ISession and thus my db-connection/transactions).

So the question is, let's say you're a developer of a module that would like to register models into entity-framework (similar to ASP.NET identity module), you won't want to have a base DbContext that the consuming application must inherit, because it would prevent them from consuming other modules (e.g. ASP.NET identity's IdentityDbContext). So what are my options? 
Is there any way to register models into a DbContext class without requiring to inherit from a DbContext? Is overriding OnModelCreating the only way to get access to a ModelBuilder?

Comment: This is still an issue with EF. Manipulating the model via extensions only works if you also don't need access to the other virtual methods. So by IdentityDbContext being so necessary for most applications, developers are forced to either have their library users call their extensions manually (no way to check if this is done at compile-time) or create a duplicate of their context which also derives from IdentityDbContext. This obviously is a poor solution because it ignores any other library the user needs which may have its own context...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your comparison is entirely fair. (Although I'm the first to admit that NHibernate beats EF in many areas).

With NHibernate, usually you load objects by some generic method in which you supply the type you want to load. You *could* create `ISession` implementations with hard-coded `Query<T>` (or `QueryOver<T>`) properties, like...

```
public Query<MyUser> Users { get; set; }
```

...and you'd have the same "problem" that you can't merge, or inherit from, two different implementations.

Likewise, you *could* work with EF by loading objects by using `context.Set<T>` only. You could even inject the configuration (sort of) by supplying `EntityTypeConfiguration` classes (as a list) in the context's constructor, storing them in a member variable and adding them to the model builder in the `OnModelCreating` override.

These specialized context classes, like `IdentityDbContext`, are offered to make life easier if they suit you. They have hard-coded `DbSet` properties (among others). The fact that you can't multiple inherit them is not a design flaw. It's just a (non-negotiable) language specification.

Choose the one that most closely serves your needs (propably `CmsDbContext`) and add other class mappings yourself.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I don't care about having a property on my DbContext. In fact I prefer dbcontext.Set<T>, so there's no problem there. My question is only about registering entity types to the dbcontext in the first place. The only way I know how to do so in EF is through ModelBuilder, and the only way to access the model builder is by overriding OnModelCreating method on DbContext class. Which means if you want to reuse the registration from ASP.NET identity is by inheriting the provided IdentityDbContext base class (which contains the OnModelCreating implementation)...

Comment: ... but that assumes that's the only component I want to use. Now if I have multiple such base DbContexts, what can I do? In nhibernate you can have as many independent components that you want, each one comes with their own set of entity mappings (either via embedded hbm or fluent mapping). I can't figure out how to do so in EF. All examples only talk about inheriting from 1 component (usually IdentityDbContext). Nobody ever talks about any second component

Comment: Btw IdentityDbContext is not provided to make your life easier. It is something that you *must* have in order for the module to work at all. It's not merely a wrapper for DbSet properties, I don't care about that. It contains implementation of OnModelCreating and ValidateEntity methods, which are the configurations required for it to work (entity registration, property mappings, entity relationships, and validation rules)

Comment: Well, it doesn't change the way you have to work with these classes. Choose one of them. That's just how it is. I don't disagree with you by the way. I think it's a good idea (and feasible) to have injectable configurations in EF or to implement auto discovery. I only use EF because its LINQ implementation is much better, but sometimes it's tantalizing to see all these NHibernate features...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by choose one of them? You mean I can only choose 1 single library that uses EF? I.e. either I choose to use ASP.NET identity, or a CMS engine, or a Product Catalogue engine, or a ShoppingCart engine, but not two (or more) of them within the same application?

Of course that *does* change everything about the way I work with these classes: I can't use them.

Comment: Oh no, you can use as many as you like. I only meant to say, since multiple inheriting them is impossible you have to choose one as base *for each context* you like to use.

Comment: Sorry but that's contradictory. I posted the question because in EF the only way (that I know) to reuse configurations from other components is by inheriting a base DbContext, because inheriting OnModelCreating is the only way to configure your models. That's why I asked whether there's another way. What you're saying is just confirming that i can only have one

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you can have multiple context classes, each inheriting from `DbContext` in the end, but of course you can use any pre-built specialized context classes side-by-side with them, or inherit from them and override their `OnModelCreating` to add more classes. But i's always `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: Having multiple DbContexts is not practical unless they are really entirely separate databases. For instance you can't have a model that references to another model that belongs to a different DbContext. Each DbContext will also create a new "first-level-cache" (in nhibernate lingo), change-tracker, new database connection, and new transaction, so u suddenly need dts. That's not what I want. I want to have one DbContext, but need a modular way to build its model configurations from multiple components

Comment: Contexts (just as sessions) should be short-lived, so it's not a point that they have their own cache. And it's perfectly sane to have multiple context classes in one application (I do this all the time). DTC will only kick in if you want them to cooperate in one transaction *and* they have different connection strings. Your last comment makes me understand your wariness better. Much of it is based on the way you think you're supposed to work with EF.

Comment: Yes context is short lived but not the point. First-level-cache is a unit-of-work, i.e. you'll get only one instance created for each entity id, whose lifecycle is tracked and saved accordingly throughout the life of the dbcontext instance, therefore **you can't reference any entity that belongs to a different dbcontext**. E.g. you can't reference the User entity (configured in IdentityDbContext) from the rest of your application (e.g. Article entity, configured in CmsDbContext), making it useless unless you can "fuse" IdentityDbContext and CmsDbContext together.

Comment: I think the root of my problem is that there is no way in EF to use ModelBuilder other than by inheriting DbContext class. Since you can't have multiple inheritance, that becomes a problem. Is there any way you know of accessing ModelBuilder without inheriting DbContext? And if so, I would raise to ASP.NET identity team (and other EF-based projects) to refactor their code away from using DbContext inheritance (e.g. IdentityDbContext), because if they all do that way, they won't ever play nice with each other