# Reusing DbContext interface without multiple inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework

- EF 6.x, .NET 4.51
- I have read on SO various posts about this including [DbContext Multiple Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28737686/dbcontext-multiple-inheritance)

I have an interface defined for all the tables and stored procedures in my database. The idea is that this interface will be used across a number of solutions with **different** DbContexts which have **different** inheritance hierachies and no common ancestor.

```
 public interface IMyDbContext : IDisposable
 {
    IDbSet<Reference_CountryModel> Reference_Country { get; set; }
    List<UspGetCountryListReturnDto> UspGetCountryList(out int aProcResult);
    List<UspGetBrandByWebsiteListReturnDto> UspGetBrandByWebsiteList(DbContext aDbContext, short? aWebsiteId, out int aProcResult)
 }
```

So lets assume my first DB context is:

```
public class MyFirstDbContext : DbContext, IMyDbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Reference_CountryConfiguration()); 
    }

    public IDbSet<Reference_CountryModel> Reference_Country { get; set; }
    public List<UspGetCountryListReturnDto> UspGetCountryList(out int aProcResult)
    {
        SqlParameter procResultParam = new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@procResult", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Direction = ParameterDirection.Output};

        List<UspGetCountryListReturnDto> procResultData = Database.SqlQuery<UspGetCountryListReturnDto>("EXEC @procResult = [dbo].[usp_GetCountryList] ", procResultParam).ToList();

        aProcResult = (int) procResultParam.Value;
        return procResultData;
    }

    public List<UspGetBrandByWebsiteListReturnDto> UspGetBrandByWebsiteList(DbContext aDbContext, short? aWebsiteId, out int aProcResult)
    {
        SqlParameter websiteIdParam = new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@WebsiteID", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.SmallInt, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = aWebsiteId.GetValueOrDefault()};
        SqlParameter procResultParam = new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@procResult", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Direction = ParameterDirection.Output};

        List<UspGetBrandByWebsiteListReturnDto> procResultData =
            aDbContext.Database.SqlQuery<UspGetBrandByWebsiteListReturnDto>("EXEC @procResult = [dbo].[usp_GetBrandByWebsiteList] @WebsiteID", websiteIdParam, procResultParam).ToList();

        aProcResult = (int) procResultParam.Value;
        return procResultData;
    }
}
```

and my second data context (AbpDbContext descends from DbContext) is:

```
public class MySecondDbContext : AbpDbContext, IMyDbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Reference_CountryConfiguration()); 
    }

    public IDbSet<Reference_CountryModel> Reference_Country { get; set; }
    public List<UspGetCountryListReturnDto> UspGetCountryList(out int aProcResult)
    {
        SqlParameter procResultParam = new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@procResult", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Direction = ParameterDirection.Output};

        List<UspGetCountryListReturnDto> procResultData = Database.SqlQuery<UspGetCountryListReturnDto>("EXEC @procResult = [dbo].[usp_GetCountryList] ", procResultParam).ToList();

        aProcResult = (int) procResultParam.Value;
        return procResultData;
    }
     public List<UspGetBrandByWebsiteListReturnDto> UspGetBrandByWebsiteList(DbContext aDbContext, short? aWebsiteId, out int aProcResult)
    {
        SqlParameter websiteIdParam = new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@WebsiteID", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.SmallInt, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = aWebsiteId.GetValueOrDefault()};
        SqlParameter procResultParam = new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@procResult", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Direction = ParameterDirection.Output};

        List<UspGetBrandByWebsiteListReturnDto> procResultData =
            aDbContext.Database.SqlQuery<UspGetBrandByWebsiteListReturnDto>("EXEC @procResult = [dbo].[usp_GetBrandByWebsiteList] @WebsiteID", websiteIdParam, procResultParam).ToList();

        aProcResult = (int) procResultParam.Value;
        return procResultData;
    }
}

}
```

As you can see the code is entirely duplicated. So to reduce the code I could create a helper class such has:

```
public static class MyDbContextHelper
{

    public static void ModelCreating(DbModelBuilder aModelBuilder)
    {
        aModelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Reference_CountryConfiguration());
    }

    public static List<UspGetBrandByWebsiteListReturnDto> UspGetBrandByWebsiteList(DbContext aDbContext, short? aWebsiteId, out int aProcResult)
    {
        SqlParameter websiteIdParam = new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@WebsiteID", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.SmallInt, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = aWebsiteId.GetValueOrDefault()};
        SqlParameter procResultParam = new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@procResult", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Direction = ParameterDirection.Output};

        List<UspGetBrandByWebsiteListReturnDto> procResultData =
            aDbContext.Database.SqlQuery<UspGetBrandByWebsiteListReturnDto>("EXEC @procResult = [dbo].[usp_GetBrandByWebsiteList] @WebsiteID", websiteIdParam, procResultParam).ToList();

        aProcResult = (int) procResultParam.Value;
        return procResultData;
    }

    public List<UspGetCountryListReturnDto> UspGetCountryList(out int aProcResult)
    {
        SqlParameter procResultParam = new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@procResult", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Direction = ParameterDirection.Output};

        List<UspGetCountryListReturnDto> procResultData = Database.SqlQuery<UspGetCountryListReturnDto>("EXEC @procResult = [dbo].[usp_GetCountryList] ", procResultParam).ToList();

        aProcResult = (int) procResultParam.Value;
        return procResultData;
    }
```

and then amend the classes that implement IMyDbContext to:

```
public class MyFirstDbContext : DbContext, IMyDbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        MyDbContextHelper.ModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public IDbSet<Reference_CountryModel> Reference_Country { get; set; }
    public List<UspGetCountryListReturnDto> UspGetCountryList(out int aProcResult)
    {
         return MyDbContextHelper.UspGetCountryList(this, aProcResult);  
    }
}
```

On the upside the implementation is contained to only MyDbContextHelper.

On the downside for each class that implements IMyDbContext and the interface changes I still have to:

1. When a dataset is added: Add the IDbSet<> properties
2. When a new method is added: Implement method in helper, Add stub method to invoke the helper

I don't see any way of getting away from 1. & 2.? Has anybody got any refinements or suggestions that would further reduce the amount of code that has to be written when the IMyDbContext interface changes? Can anyone see any issues with the above approach?

Comment: This looks like DbContext Abuse. Why not just use something like dapper instead of making a mess of the DbContext?

Comment: @Phill EF is used internally for other reasons, so I would prefer to have an EF centric solution instead of adding yet another dependency on a 3rd party solution like Dapper which I then have to manage and support. So if I have to "abuse" DbContext then that is preferred to introducing yet another abstraction that has to be managed.

Comment: There is a common ancestor though. `DbContext`. The interface is unneeded because of that. Really all you need is the helper method you already wrote.

Comment: @Shoe The interface is there to enforce the contract and obviously for testing so it can be mocked. The common create ancestor would assist with doing all the model configuration, but not with the duplicated methods and properties - unless I have missed your intention?

Comment: That's not going to be useful though if all your implementation is going to do is call `AdHoc_UspGetPassengerCountByAge`. Likely you want to test the helper method. In that case you have to mock DbContext anyway because that's what the parameters are.

Comment: I Assume you're using SQL Server, why are you not using parameterized queries for your TVP query?

Comment: I would abstract your adhoc queries using a query pattern where you have IDbQuery<T> and then a couple of helper functions like .Single(...) or .Collection(IDbQuery...), then you get your reusability, and testing, and no messy abstraction.

Comment: If you don't mind changing `AbpDbContext`, then you could add an abstract class that both `MyFirstDbContext` and `AbpDbContext` can inherit.

Comment: @Phill I copied and pasted some code for an edge case by mistake (in that case the field names in the database could not map to property names for the DTO so I had to execute a dynamic query to do some renaming). Added anadditional method UspGetBrandByWebsiteList() to show a more representative example of parameter usage etc. And yes back end is SQL Server.

Comment: @sstan Cannot change AbpDbContext as that class is required by ASP Boilerplate (http://aspnetboilerplate.com/) for it to work.

Comment: @Shoe I wouldn't mock DBContext, I would mock the helper as all I needed to test would be the results it returns. It would never go near a database, but totally from memory.

Comment: @Phill "...abstract adhoc quieries" Those are not abstract queries, those are stored procedure calls into a namespace called "Adhoc". What I have not shown is that we have a repository abstraction in front of these classes that provide the query abstraction you mention.